# libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2 . . . No such file or directory

Tags: install, libraries

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04, and now my Emacs (25.1.1), working fine before, is broken. Here is the error from running `emacs --debug-init`

```
emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've seen (older) answers that hit around this issue, but this problem came from a simple Ubuntu upgrade...

Comment: Did you compile Emacs yourself? If so, you may need to recompile it after upgrading the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success. Apparently, it does take a recompile/install, albeit with a `./configure CFLAGS=-no-pie` to start with. Not sure why. I installed/reinstalled everything `libMagickWand`-ish Synaptic had to offer beforehand.

Comment: PIE isn't supported: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18784

Comment: If this answer resolves your problem, please accept it so we can mark this post as done.

Comment: if you compile a program that depends on a shared library, and then you replace the shared library with a newer version, your compiled program can't use the old version anymore, so it's broken. Your package manager deals with this for you for packaged programs, but anything you compile yourself needs to be recompiled.